# Method iterator() declared in java.util.Collection and in java.lang.Iterable, its superinterface?

Tags: java, collections

Can somebody explain to me why is the method `Iterator<E> iterator();` defined in `java.util.Collection`? Collection already extends `java.lang.Iterable`; this method is redundant. Is this for convenience?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`Collection` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) was introduced in Java 1.2 with the Collections API.  The `iterator` method was present then.  However, the [`Iterable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) wasn't introduced until Java 1.5.  The reason that `Collection` explicitly defines `iterator` is because it predates `Iterable`.  The idea of a `Collection` returning an `Iterator` predates the idea of `Iterable`.

Comment: Okay, why it was not removed from Collection in java1.5?  Is it not backward-compatible?

Comment: There was no reason to remove it from `Collection` when making `Collection` extend the new `Iterable` interface.

Comment: First of all it confuse me.))

Comment: To remove it would break backward compatibility. That is, people wrote programs in 1999 that used `Iterator i = myList.iterator()`. Removing the method from the interface would cause those programs to stop compiling.

Comment: There is a lot of old code in the JDK that was left in place for continued support of user applications developed during earlier versions of Java. Whenever the Java team roles out new design, they typically mark the previous code as "deprecated" so when you compile you will see a warning that the code you are using is no longer recommended. You can even deprecate code yourself using the @Deprecated annotation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html).

Comment: @IlyaK. One could say that they didn't removed it for follow the ["open/closed principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) (The Java engineers like to keep the backward compatibility).

Comment: @slim I don't understand why code `Iterator i = myList.iterator()` will not work on >= JDK 1.5. On compilation and on binary level it's backward compatible.

Comment: It  *does* work, only because they left that method in the interface. Your question was why they did not remove it.

Comment: @slim removing the method from `Collection` while it is inherited from `Iterable` would not break compatibility with `Iterator i = myList.iterator();`. That’s the whole point of inheritance and the OP’s question. The only thing that wouldn’t work anymore, would be something like `Collection.class.getDeclaredMethod("iterator")`. But rgettman already nailed it, there’s simply no reason to remove the method.